# Brownian motion with zero volatility

Tags: brownian-motion

is it possible for Brownian motion to deal with zero volatility? and if it does, does it mean that the fund experiencing deterministic increment in value?

Comment: This question is missing a lot of context/is ill-specified. Brownian motion (a.k.a. Wiener process) has variance $\operatorname{Var}(W_t) = t$, which is nonzero for any $t > 0$. Are you asking if it's possible to make an Ito process with variance zero? In this case, the answer is yes: $dX_t = \mu dt + 0 dW_t$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will improve that. So, we are left with dXt = mdt. Let's have m = 0.03. In this case, does its value same as the future value of a fund, for instance, St+1 = St(1.03)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your comments, what I think you really want to ask is "what happens when I have a **geometric** Brownian motion with constant drift and zero volatility?"

Let $m$ be a constant and consider the stochastic differential equation
$$dS_t = m S_t dt + 0 \cdot S_t dW_t = m S_t dt.$$
Because the drift can be written $\mu(t, S_t) \equiv m S_t$, the above is actually an [ordinary differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation).
Apply Ito's lemma (which in this case degenerates to the ordinary [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)) to $f(S_t) = \log S_t$ to get
\begin{multline*}
\log S_T
= f(S_T)
= f(S_0) + \int_0^T f^\prime(S_t) dS_t
= \log S_0 + \int_0^T \frac{1}{S_t} m S_t dt
\\= \log S_0 + \int_0^T m dt
= \log S_0 + m T.
\end{multline*}
Exponentiating both sides,
$$
S_T = S_0 \exp(m T).
$$
It seems to me that you are using some finance terminology, so if it helps, you can think of the above as a bond that pays out continuously compounded interest at rate $m$.